# jQuery in Adobe Edge Animate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

The problem is, that a jQuery command isn't executed. I have this jQuery Code:

```
$('#Stage_myButton').click(function() {
    $('#Stage_myElement').animate({top: '1000px'});
});
```

Now if I insert an alert, the alert will be done, but the element myElement doesn't change position. When I enter the same command in the Console from the browser the position changes.

Comment: can you show some more code?

Comment: Thats all the js code there is. The other js animations are handled with css classes. It's called in the compositionReady Event from the Stage.

Comment: Are you sure that code executes after the html has been parsed?

Comment: Yes when I add a alert with some text in it, the alert shows itself after the button has been clicked.

Comment: And I assume that your script is not located between Stage_myButton and Stage_myElement elements?

Comment: Can you post it on JSfiddle or something?

Comment: I wrote the script after I pressed the shortcut ctrl+E to open the scripting window, when the stage was selected. I'm pretty new to Edge Animate so I dont know very much about it.

Comment: But then the elements would be missing wouldn't they? Furthermore, I don't think I'm allowed to upload the code, because it belongs to the company I'm working at.